# Stop NSTimer when leaving view

Tags: ios, xcode, nstimer

I am working on something that will take data from a website every time the counter counts down. The issue is that I want the counter to stop when the user leaves the view and not keep retrieving data. I have been trying to add this in,

```
[timername invalidate];
```

to no avail. Can someone tell me what I need to do so the timer stops when the view is left and re-starts from new when someone goes back to the view?

Thanks.

```
#import "Price.h"

@interface Price ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *priceLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *countdownLabel;


@end

@implementation Price
int counter;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    counter = 10;

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:(self) selector:@selector(countdown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(void)getPrice{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myURL"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error ==nil){
             NSDictionary *spotPrice = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL]
             ;
             self.priceLabel.text = [[[spotPrice objectForKey:@"amount"] stringByAppendingString:@" "]stringByAppendingString:[spotPrice objectForKey:@"currency"]];
         }

     }];
}

-(void)countdown{
    counter--;
    self.countdownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", counter];
    if (counter == 0){
        counter = 15;
        [self getPrice];
```

Answer (score 2):

For do it, You need to set `@property` of your `NSTimer` and  write

```
[_timername invalidate];
 _timername = nil;
```

to `viewWillDisappear:` method.

Such like,,

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [_timername invalidate];
    _timername = nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks You for the info.  I added that in and it runs however when I leave the view and go back, my counter does not restart from 10.  it will re-start from 8.  If I leave and go back one more time, the counter will re-start from 7 and so on.  There seems to be a glitch in my counter code.  I was hoping this would re-start the counter each time I left and went back but it doesn't.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why write a property if you're just going to access the iVar directly?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if ([timername isValid]) {
            [timername invalidate];
            timername = nil;
        }
    });
}
```